# Getting Different Output when i use f string in python

Tags: python, oop, pycharm, f-string

```
    #Make a class that represents a bank account. Create four methods named set_details, display, withdraw and deposit.
    #     In the set_details method, create two instance variables : name and balance. The default value for balance should
    #     be
    # zero. In the display method, display the values of these two instance variables.
    #
    #     Both the methods withdraw and deposit have amount as parameter. Inside withdraw, subtract the amount from balance
    # and inside deposit, add the amount to the balance.
    #
       # Create two instances of this class and call the methods on those instances.
    class bank:

        def set_details(self, name, balance=0):
            self.name = name,
            self.balance = balance,


        def display(self):
            print(f"name = {self.name}. Balance = {self.balance}"),



        def withdraw(self, a):
            self.balance -= a,
            print(f"Balance after withdrawn {self.balance}")


        def deposite(self, b):
            self.balance += b,
            print(f"Balance after deposite {self.balance}")

    ankit = bank()
    ankit.set_details("ankit", "2300")
    ankit.display()
```

output

(venv) C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\ankitt>bank.py
name = ('ankit',). Balance = ('2300',)

output wanted
name = ankit. balance = 2300

why the round brackets appears with the quotes and commas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
    def set_details(self, name, balance=0):
            self.name = name,
            self.balance = balance,
```

Remove the commas after both assignments. Having the commas there assigns them as `tuples` rather than their actual type.

Also, as Marcel Wilson mentioned in the comments, remove the commas from `withdraw` and `deposite` as well.

```py
        def withdraw(self, a):
            self.balance -= a,
            print(f"Balance after withdrawn {self.balance}")


        def deposite(self, b):
            self.balance += b,
            print(f"Balance after deposite {self.balance}")
```

Comment: Same thing with the diposite and withdraw methods; remove the comma after `self.balance += a` and `self.balance -= b`

Comment: Correct, didn't notice those. Good catch!

Comment: I've been using python for over 10 year and this one stumped me at first too. We are always learning.

Comment: @MarcelWilson please check my 1 more problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61085931/how-to-access-instance-object-in-list-and-display-there-data-in-python