# How to access instance object in list and display there data? in python

Tags: python

```
class Bank:

    def __init__(self, name, balance=0):
        self.name = name
        self.balance = balance


    # def Display_details(self):
    #     print( self.name),
    #     print(self.balance),
    #
    #
    #
    # def Withdraw(self, a):
    #     self.balance -= a
    #     print(f"Balance after withdrawn {self.balance}")
    #
    #
    # def Deposite(self, b):
    #     self.balance += b
    #     print(f"Balance after deposite {self.balance}")

class Book:
    def __init__(self,isbn, title, author, publisher, pages, price, copies):
        self.isbn = isbn
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.publisher = publisher
        self.pages = pages
        self.price = price
        self.copies = copies

    def display(self):
        print(f"isbn = {self.isbn}")
        print(f"title = {self.title}")
        print(f"price = {self.price}")
        print(f"copies = {self.copies}")

    def in_stock(self):
        if self.copies > 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def shell(self):
        for i in range(self.copies, 0):
                    if self.copies == 0:
                        print('the book is out of stock')
                    else:
                        self.copies -= 1
                        print(self.copies)

book1 = Book('957-4-36-547417-1', 'Learn Physics','Stephen', 'CBC', 350, 200,10)
book2 = Book('652-6-86-748413-3', 'Learn Chemistry','Jack', 'CBC', 400, 220,20)
book3 = Book('957-7-39-347216-2', 'Learn Maths','John', 'XYZ', 500, 300,5)
book4 = Book('957-7-39-347216-2', 'Learn Biology','Jack', 'XYZ', 400, 200,6)

book_list = [book1, book2, book3, book4]

for i in book_list:
     print(i.display)
# print(book1.display())
```

How to access instance object in list and display them?

```
<bound method Book.display of <__main__.Book object at 0x0000000001D88880>>
<bound method Book.display of <__main__.Book object at 0x0000000001D88CD0>>
<bound method Book.display of <__main__.Book object at 0x0000000001D88BB0>>
<bound method Book.display of <__main__.Book object at 0x00000000007A7400>
```

its display the book from the instance object declaration and why the 
main.Book object at 0x00000000007A7400> 
is display
 is there and use of `__str__` and `__repr__` in this?

if i remove the comment from the last line and comment the 2nd line

print(book1.display())

```
(venv) C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\ankitt>bank.py
isbn = 957-4-36-547417-1
title = Learn Physics
price = 200
copies = 10
None
```

Comment: what is your question here? `i.display != i.display()`

Comment: you need to call the method, so  `i.display()` not `i.display` and dont print them

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? You're very clearly not calling the method, which means that this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130574/bound-method-error. As an aside, using `i` as the variable name in the loop is a bad idea here. Also, the `shell()` methods looks quite strange.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're facing is you've printed the method `i.display_text` itself when what you want is to either print what the method returns or let the method print for you.

You need to decide where you want the `print()` function to occur. You can either call `display()` and let it print for you or have display return the text and print it.

Generally I would advise you to not use `print` inside your methods.  Keep your class simple.

## Option 1:

Don't call print in your loop and be sure to make `i.display()` a call not a reference.

```py
for i in book_list:
     i.display()
```

## Option 2:

Call print in your loop but have your method return the string. (I took some liberties with formatting)

```py
    def display_text(self):
        return (
        f"isbn = {self.isbn} \n"
        f"title = {self.title} \n"
        f"price = {self.price} \n"
        f"copies = {self.copies} \n"
        )
...
for i in book_list:
     print(i.display_text())
```

## Option 3:

Use a `__str__` or `__repr__` method on the class and simply print the instance. This is useful during debugging as well as simply printing the information on screen.  You'll be able to identify which Book instance is which much easier.

```py
    def __str__(self):
        return ( f"Book<{self.isbn} '{self.title}' ${self.price} {self.copies}>")
...
for i in book_list:
    print(i)
```

will output this:

```
Book<957-4-36-547417-1 'Learn Physics' $200 10>
Book<652-6-86-748413-3 'Learn Chemistry' $220 20>
Book<957-7-39-347216-2 'Learn Maths' $300 5>
Book<957-7-39-347216-2 'Learn Biology' $200 6>
```

---

**Bonus points:**

You could also make your `display()` method a `@property` which allows you to reference it without the normal call parenthesis. See [properties](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties).

example:

```py
    @property
    def display_text(self):
        return (
        f"isbn = {self.isbn} \n"
        f"title = {self.title} \n"
        f"price = {self.price} \n"
        f"copies = {self.copies} \n"
        )

...
for i in book_list:
     print(i.display_text)
```